# Run a list of macros after macro before finishes

Tags: excel, vba, time

I have 9 macros that I need to call. I have them now as follows:

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

If Weekday(Date) >= 2 And Weekday(Date) < 7 Then
    
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("15:14:00"), "MarketClose3"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("17:15:00"), "Saveit"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("17:18:00"), "MASTER"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("17:34:00"), "MASTER"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("17:50:00"), "MASTER"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("18:06:00"), "MASTER"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("18:22:00"), "MASTER"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("18:38:00"), "MASTER"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("18:54:00"), "MASTER"
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("19:10:00"), "SORT"
End If
    
End Sub
```

The first one (that calls MarketClose3) is fine. What I am wondering is how I can call "Saveit" at 17:15 and then run it, and then call "Master" 5 minutes after "Saveit" is done. Then I would like to call "Master" another 6 times while waiting 5 minutes after each time it runs, then finally call "SORT". If I leave them with predetermined times, they run into each other and take a lot longer than they need to.

Comment: @SolarMike That question just doesn't have an answer

Comment: But if you made the effort to edit and re-phrase it to improve it instead of duplicate postings it would be appreciated by many on the site. And I gave you a possible idea of how to approach solving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do this - have the macro you want to loop call itself with a parameter:

```vb
Sub Workbook_Open()
    If Weekday(Date) >= 2 And Weekday(Date) < 7 Then
        Application.OnTime TimeValue("15:14:00"), "MarketClose3"
    End If
End Sub

Sub MarketClose3()
    'do the work...
    'call next step
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 3, 0), "Saveit"
End Sub

Sub Saveit()
    'do the work...
    'call next step (Master) and tell it to run 5 times
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 3, 0), "'Master " & 5 & "'"
End Sub

Sub Master(Optional n As Long = 0)
    'do the work
    
    'schedule the next run if needed (when n > 0), or call the final method
    If n > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Master called with " & n
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 5, 0), "'Master " & (n - 1) & "'"
    Else
        SortIt 'would avoid using Sort as a method name...
    End If
End Sub

Sub SortIt()
    'do the work
End Sub
```

Comment: I like where you are going with this. Then how would I set up my code to call "Saveit" and "Sort" at the right times

Comment: In the example above if `n = 0` you could call SORT

Comment: Exactly how you'd do this really depends on whether this is the only use case for these macros, or do they also need to be run outside of this scheduled approach.

Comment: This is the only time that I use these macros. I just need to call "Saveit" right at 17:15 and then the macro named "Master" after "Saveit" runs after waiting 3 minutes. Then I will call Master 6 more times (with 3 minute breaks in between each time "Master" is called). Then when those are all done I need to call "Sort". I know this is confusing but extremely helpful to me

Comment: See my update above.